# Is it possible to deploy a MFP v6.3 runtime with a higher level than the MFP Console and Services applications?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I know that there is a separation of the lifecycle of the MFP Studio and MFP Server. What happens if the development team updated the Studio with a fix? In other words, is it supported to deploy a runtime for example v6.3.0.00.20150214-1702 to a MFP Server v6.3.0.00.20141127-1357?

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you've described it a supported scenario. The MFP Server should be able to host a .war file generated from a newer MFP Studio build of the same major version (6.3, and I believe support from this scenario exists starting 6.1 or 6.2).

Of course, if you encounter a problem you should probably open a PMR on that. :)